# How to insert a new column into a table , the table exist?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I want to insert a new row into a table call s_criteria. The columns are module_name, include_list, created_by and date.
how do you create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
insert 
  into s_criteria ( module_name, include_list , created_by, date )
values ( 'max_days', 366, 'me', to_date('08/30/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') );
```

Comment: im sorry i was not specific , i actually want to insect new data , i want to module_name=max_days, include_list= 366, create=me, date=8/30/2013

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME>
ADD <COLUMNNAME> <DATATYPE>;
----------------------------
THEN USE
INSERT COMMAND TO INSERT VALUE INTO TABLE
```